# Laravel Guzzle error when post to url in job queue

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle6

In my job,I am using guzzle to call api abc.com/test
Sometime, when a lot of job in application. Job become fail
**cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: router; Unknown error (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)**
All endpoint which use guzzle changed to "router".

```
$config = [ 
    'verify' => false,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
];
$this->httpClient = new Client($config);
$response = $this->httpClient->request("POST",'abc.com/updateProduct', $data)
```

Comment: Can you please show some code that could help in seeing what you are doing?

Comment: $config = [
            'verify' => false,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        ];
        $this->httpClient = new Client($config);
$response = $this->httpClient->request("POST",'abc.com/updateProduct',  $data).

Answer (score 1):

we just ran into the same issue and for us downgrading our NewRelic PHP Agent solved the issue, more info: https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-php-agent/issues/255

Comment: For us disabling Guzzle support in NewRelic PHP agent was enough: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/php-agent/frameworks-libraries/guzzle/#disable-guzzle-support
`newrelic.guzzle.enabled = false`